# PHP 7 - How to search for multiple specific members of an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a PHP array that looks like this:

```
array (size=3)
  'CA,Santa Barbara' => 
    array (size=2)
      'state' => string 'CA' (length=2)
      'city' => string 'Santa Barbara' (length=13)
  'KS,Andover' => 
    array (size=2)
      'state' => string 'KS' (length=2)
      'city' => string 'Andover' (length=7)
  'KS,Wichita' => 
    array (size=2)
      'state' => string 'KS' (length=2)
      'city' => string 'Wichita' (length=7)
```

I need to return all the array members who have the values:

```
state => 'KS'
```

I am needing to get an array back that looks like this:

```
array (size=2)
  'KS,Andover' => 
    array (size=2)
      'state' => string 'KS' (length=2)
      'city' => string 'Andover' (length=7)
  'KS,Wichita' => 
    array (size=2)
      'state' => string 'KS' (length=2)
      'city' => string 'Wichita' (length=7)
```

Is there a PHP array function that does this?
I have found array_search() but that only returns the first match. I need ALL matches.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`array_filter()`](https://php.net/array_filter) to remove all unneeded values:

```
$array = [
    'CA,Santa Barbara' => ['state' => 'CA', 'city' => 'Santa Barbara'],
    'KS,Andover'       => ['state' => 'KS', 'city' => 'Andover'],
    'KS,Wichita'       => ['state' => 'KS', 'city' => 'Wichita'],
];

$state = 'KS';
$out   = array_filter($array, fn($v) => $v['state'] == $state);
print_r($out);
```

Outputs:

```
Array(
    [KS,Andover] => Array(
            [state] => KS
            [city] => Andover
        )
    [KS,Wichita] => Array(
            [state] => KS
            [city] => Wichita
        )
)
```

You can also use type hinting to get a better data flow control:

```php
$out = array_filter($array, fn(array $v): bool => $v['state'] == $state);
#                              ^          ^
#                              |          |
#                              |          array_filter's callback returns
#                              |          a boolean (true to keep,
#                              |          false to remove).
#                              |
#                              each elements of the $array
#                              are arrays.
```

**Before PHP 7.4**, (without [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php)), you have to use the keyword `use` to pass the `$state` variable to the anonymous function:

```
$state = 'KS';
$out   = array_filter($array, function($v) use ($state) {
    return $v['state'] == $state;
});
print_r($out);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Follow up...How would I pass a variable into the function to replace 'KS' with a value that changes with every loop?

Comment: @EricSnyder You can use `use()`. See the updated answer.